# The smaller the population, the higher likelihood of the medical staff shortage. Is it true?

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

The problem statement:

> Suppose we have a city with 100 doctors and the population of 1 million. Probability that a person will need a doctor on a given day is $1\%$. What is the probability that there won’t be enough doctors on a given day?

- By "not enough doctors" I assume it is meant that on a given day, there will be more people ($> 100$) seeking medical advice than there are doctors that can provide it.
- We further assume that $100$ doctors **are not included in the population**.

Seems like the most reasonable option here is to use binomial random variable. Using [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+combination%2810%5E6%2Cx%29*%280.01%5Ex%29*%280.99%5E%2810%5E6-x%29%29+for+x%3D101+to+10%5E6) gives

$$\sum_{x=101}^{10^6}{10^6 \choose x}0.01^x0.99^{10^6-x} \approx 0$$

Just for the sake of it, I wanted to see what the result would be given that we have a population of $10^4$. To my surprise, the result ([wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+combination%2810%5E4%2C+x%29*%280.01%5Ex%29*%280.99%5E%2810%5E4-x%29%29+for+x%3D101+to+10%5E4)) is

$$\sum_{x=101}^{10^4}{10^4 \choose x}0.01^x0.99^{10^4-x} \approx 0.47$$

Which implies that, the smaller population, the higher probability of medical staff shortage. **But shouldn't the opposite be true?** The larger the population, the more people might need to seek medical advice, hence the higher likelihood of not having enough doctors. What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: This first calculation is wrong. No idea how Wolfram calculated the summation, but it's clear that *on average*, $0.01 \times 10^6 = 10,000$ people need a doctor in a day. Do you mean that probability is 0.01**%**?

Comment: @AdamO, I meant probability of $1\%$, or $\frac{1}{100}$

Comment: Did you realize the 0 probabilty is wrong? It would be instructive to correct the probability calculation. You can use R and pbinom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you're running into computational issues with Wolfram Alpha trying to do an exact calculation with $n = 10^6$.  I tried finding the complement of the probability you were looking for, figuring that would be simpler, and I got a notification saying the calculation timed out. Splitting up that calculation in to two parts (0-50 people need a doctor and 51-100 people need a doctor), I didn't get that error, and both probabilities were approximately 0, so combining them would also yield 0.  This would then imply that the probability that more than 100 people need a doctor is essentially 1.

As AdamO mentioned in the comments above, we should expect an average of 10,000 people per day to need a doctor if $p = 1%$.  If you compute $P(x>100)$ using a normal approximation to the binomial distribution, you should find this probability is basically 1.